# Google Shopping API - deleting data. What do i use as the id?

Tags: google-shopping-api

Which of the fields below do i use as an id? 
[image: Which one of the fields do i use as an id?]

Trying id always gives a 400 so I am unsure what to use. I have tried the test console and this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest ID to use consists of
channel:language:targetcountry:productid

so for the above example the rest id would be
online:en:NZ:118042

Answer (score 1):

> If you just delete the product from the website it will remove it from the feed.

- Google Support